# Accessing Object's Data Via Another Variable Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

It's super late and my mind is blanking right now, but let's say I have variable `filename` and it's storing the name of another variable `marker`. The variable `marker` is an array and contains the object & property `position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2550,-114.3221)`.

I've been stupidly trying to access it via `filename.position` which of course returns undefined, since it's searching the literal `filename` for a 'position' property that does not exist.

But how could I pull `marker.position` by using `filename`?  Is there some nifty jQuery trick for, uh, 'resolving' a variable to its contents?  I'm brain fried.  I know I've done this before.

Comment: Use bracket notation: `window[filename].postion`, for instance.

Comment: @apsillers It will work *only* in case if `filename` was defined globally.

Comment: Duplicate: [Access value of JavaScript variable by name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399794/access-value-of-javascript-variable-by-name)

Comment: @VisioN Yes, that's exactly why I said "for instance" -- it's an example of how bracket notation could be used to access a property of `window`. Certainly, a complete answer would explain the larger context of how to avoid globals (e.g., object namespacing), but the syntax would be identical.

Comment: God, yes, thank you. I'm retarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible in your script, you can store the data not just in variable, but in a property of some object (usually it's more convenient to use global one).
For example

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.marker = new google.maps.LatLng(42.2550,-114.3221); // or anything else
```

Then you will be able to get this property using a variable like this:

```
myObj[filename].position
```

In this case i would also recomment to check for `myObj[filename]` existance using `typeof` structure, just to make sure such property exists in `myObj`.

```
if (typeof myObj[filename] !== "undefined") {
  // do something
}
```

As apsillers noted, you could use global `window` object for this as well. But if your `marker` variable was defined inside some other function (i.e. **not global**), you **won't be able** to access it with `window.marker` or `window[filename]` as it will be out of scope.

Second way is to use eval() function which i'd strongly recommend to *avoid*.

Comment: Unfortunately, my variable was local inside another function. I then wanted to access it inside a separate jQuery function, so I had to go global with `window`. If I had the foresight, none of that would have been necessary. Not sure how to reconcile it without using globals and I'm unwilling to do a total rewrite for the nonce. Regardless, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
window[filename].position;
```