# Templates for JavaScript methods?

Tags: javascript

I recently found a document by Mike Bostock, [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/#reconfiguration), which describes some conventions for encapsulating reusable charts in [D3](http://d3js.org/). Note however that the question isn't just about D3 but rather creating methods for JavaScript objects dynamically.

His proposal includes the following snippet:

```
function chart() {
  var width = 720, // default width
      height = 80; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return my;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return my;
  };

  return my;
}
```

This is all fine but what I am immediately wondering once I started adding more chart properties than just `width` and `height` to it is whether the common parts of these "property accessor functions" could be factored out somehow.

I am imagining some method to dynamically register a property like this:

```
my.addProperty(propName) {
  my[propName] = function (value) {
                   if (!arguments.length) return getPrivateVar(propName);
                   setPrivateVar(propName, value);
                   return my;
                 };
}
```

So I could then simply do

```
my.addProperty('width');
my.addProperty('height');
```

to achieve the same result as the `my.width =` and `my.height =` statements from the code above.

Is this even possible? How?

#### EDIT:

The crux of the matter is obviously accessing the "private" variables `width` and `height` of the `chart()` function by name (represented by the `get/setPrivateVar()` method calls inside my `addProperty` idea). Therefore, answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4399794/897968) (which focus on getting a *global* variable by name) obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve your problem:

```
function chart() {
  var options = {
      width : 720, // default width
      height : 80 // default height
  };

  var my = function() {

  };

  var accessorFunction = function(object, propertyName) {
    return function(value) {
      if (!value) return options[propertyName];
      options[propertyName] = value;
      return object;
    };
  };

  for (propertyName in options) {
    my[propertyName] = accessorFunction(my, propertyName);
  }

  return my;
}

console.log(chart().width());
console.log(chart().width(721).width());
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Your `propertyNames in options` loop is a nice additional benefit of your solution. Although I would have preferred to keep the `width` and `height` variables as plain `var`s inside `chart`, I believe this is currently impossible.