# Javascript - access the value of variables with dynamic name refereed

Tags: javascript, variables

Noob question here :) Is there any way to access the value of a variable name refereed dynamically in javascript ?

What I tried :

```
var var1 = "foo";
var var2 = "bar";
var i = 1;
i++; 

console.log(`var${i}`);  // give me "var2"
console.log(typeof `var${i}`); // == srting`
```

I want to access the value "foo" or "bar" but i'm missing something as I get only the name of the variable ?

My first question on stack, so if it's not perfect let me know I will add details, thank you !

Comment: I do not think you can do this. But if your values are so related that you are naming variables after them and appending a number, why not user an array and store the values in the array and access them by index? `var valueArray = ["foo", "bar"]; var i = 0; i++; console.log(valueArray[i]);`

Comment: `var var1 = "hello"; \`${eval("var" + 1)}\`` would "work" (or `window["var" + 1]` for global variables) - this is basically just another way of asking: "How can I get the value of a variable by name?" hiding inside an interpolation, which is answered elsewhere. Note that the content of `\`..\`` is *treated as an expression*. I recommend using a proper collection instead of such .. specialness.

Comment: ie. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399794/access-value-of-javascript-variable-by-name and similar

Comment: `this['var' + i]` should get what you want no matter which scope your are in

Comment: @Frederik.L `this[..]` will only work for *properties* on "this", including *global variables* when outside of any function.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for clarifying. Yes, I meant that it will work for variables defined in the current context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variables are defined in the global scope, they are properties of the window object.

```js
var var1 = "foo";
var var2 = "bar";
var i = 1;
i++; 

console.log(window[`var${i}`]);
```

Probably a better approach is to create a data object and store variables as properties of that.

```js
var data = {};
data.var1 = "foo";
data.var2 = "bar";

var i = 1;
i++; 

console.log(data[`var${i}`]);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will try the data object as I think it's the best in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute dynamic code.

```js
var var1 = "foo";
var var2 = "bar";
var i = 1;
i++; 

console.log(eval('(var' + i + ')'));  // give me "var2"
console.log(eval('(typeof(var' + i + '))')); // == srting`
```